# Syntactic Sugar no PHP

Tags: php, syntactic-sugar

O `foreach` seria uma implementação de Syntactic Sugar no PHP?

```
foreach($array as $key=>$values) {
    //Faz algo com as chaves e valores.
}
```

Comment: Me baseando por outra linguagem de alto-nível como o C#, acredito que seja Syntatic Sugar pois não existe um `foreach`no C então ou ele é baseado num `while`ou num `for`. Eu queria ter certeza, mas não consigo achar nenhuma informação que preste em nenhum repositório de algo escrito em C >.<

Comment: @BrunoAugusto É possível fazer uma espécie de `foreach` no C e no C++, da mesma forma que o pessoal do jQuery fez uma espécie de "função foreach" (a função `each` do jQuery). [Macros também ajudam](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400951/does-c-have-a-foreach-loop-construct). Mas em C isso é mais trabalhoso, porque ao contrário do C++, no C não existe o conceito de referência.

Comment: Não conheço C, sequer consigo ler alguma coisa em C, mas isso não seria, não sei, algo como um função *user-defined* que temos nas linguagens de alto nível?

Comment: Só é syntactic sugar, se for implementado pela própria linguagem, built-in. Se for implementado pelo usuário deixa de ser, ao meu entendimento.

Comment: Sei não hein, Marcelo. Uma vez um usuário de um fórum me deu um senhor puxão de orelha porque eu havia adicionado uma classe abstrata vazia unicamente pra não implementar a mesma interface em diversas classes manualmente.

Comment: Desculpe não entendi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, se uma vez que não precisaria do mesmo para conseguir tal resultado, assim como muitas outras funções:  `while` e `do while`.

Mas, as linguagens devem evoluir e isso acaba sendo considerado natural com o tempo (afinal ninguém quer ficar escrevendo repetições `for` com `if` e `GOTO`).

Answer (score 3):

Praticamente todas as estrutura de repetição (`for`, `foreach`, `do-while`, `for-in`) das linguagens de programação mais modernas podem ser consideradas açúcar sintático para a estrutura mais simples de todas, o `while` (que está presente no PHP desde a versão 4). Então a resposta é sim.

Vale lembrar que açúcar sintático são estruturas da linguagem que permitem realizar uma tarefa de forma mais "simples" do que pela forma mais "baixo nível". Por exemplo, se formos comparar `for` e `while` no PHP:

**while:**

```
$i = 0;
while ($i <= 10):
    echo $i;
    $i++;
endwhile;
```

**for:**

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    echo $i;
}
```

A maioria das pessoas considera a segunda forma mais simples e legível. No entanto, em termos de computação, ambas as formas são equivalentes.

Answer (score 2):

Segundo o [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), sim e nao.

Por exemplo, sao identicos:

```
<?php
$arr = array("one", "two", "three");
reset($arr);
while (list(, $value) = each($arr)) {
    echo "Value: $value<br />\n";
}

foreach ($arr as $value) {
    echo "Value: $value<br />\n";
}
?>
```

e

```
<?php
$arr = array("one", "two", "three");
reset($arr);
while (list($key, $value) = each($arr)) {
    echo "Key: $key; Value: $value<br />\n";
}

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo "Key: $key; Value: $value<br />\n";
}
?>
```

contudo, ja nao sao nesse caso:

```
<?php 
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9); 

foreach($arr as $key=>$value) 
{ 
    unset($arr[$key + 1]); 
    echo $value . PHP_EOL; 
} 
?>
```

Output: 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

e nesse:

```
<?php 
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9); 

while (list($key, $value) = each($arr)) 
{ 
    unset($arr[$key + 1]); 
    echo $value . PHP_EOL; 
} 
?>
```

Output: 
1 3 5 7 9

Comment: Isso não quer dizer que não seja açúcar sintático. O output não é o mesmo nos dois últimos exemplos porque a lógica que o programa vai seguir não é a mesma - por usar unset, você está modificando o array, mas o ponteiro interno ainda irá acessar os valores que deveriam ser removidos. Com relação ao uso de `unset` dentro de uma iteração de `foreach`, o próprio manual diz o seguinte: `As foreach relies on the internal array pointer, changing it within the loop may lead to unexpected behavior.`

Comment: Concordo, mas e bom deixar claro que nem todo uso vai dar na mesma.

Comment: O que ele quis dizer, é que seria possível fazer coisas similares com estas funções, a forma que implementa pode mudar, mas pode chegar ao mesmo resultado.